# extension URL: 'weak' may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types, not 'URL'

Tags: swift3

```
extension URL {
        func toJPEGData(beginAsync: ((Void) -> Void)?, endAsync: ((Void) -> Void)?, quality: ImageQualityEnum, completion: @escaping (Data?, BBError?) -> Void) {
             let scheme = self.scheme, URLString = self.absoluteString
             if scheme == "assets-library" {
        let assets: PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [self], options: nil)
        guard let asset = assets.firstObject else {
            completion(irrelevant)
            return
        }
        beginAsync?()
        PHImageManager.default() .requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: PHImageContentMode.aspectFit, options: nil) {
            [weak self] (image, info) in
```

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ I'm getting NSURLExtension.swift:91:23: 'weak' may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types, not 'URL'

what is going on here <s>in a snippet that used to compile and work just fine in 2.3</s>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSURL` is a class, `URL` is a struct, the error message says that  *'weak' may only be applied to class...*.

That means, `[weak self]` cannot be used in `URL`, make the extension an extension of `NSURL` or use `[unowned self]`.

Comment: Ok, I'll keep extending NSURL then. Any ideas how to convert back and forth between the two?

Comment: Just bridge them `as URL`, `as NSURL` (no exclamation, no question mark)

Comment: FYI, you cannot use `unowned` with value types, either.